# Make axis ticks labels bold when using usetex=True

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex, yaxis, x-axis

I want to have bold labels on my axis, so I can use the plot for publication. I also need to have the label of the lines in the legend plotted in bold.
So far I can set the axis labels and the legend to the size and weight I want. I can also set the size of the axis labels to the size I want, however I am failing with the weight.

Here is an example code:

```
# plotting libs
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import rc


if __name__=='__main__':

  tmpData = np.random.random( 100 )


  # activate latex text rendering
  rc('text', usetex=True)
  rc('axes', linewidth=2)
  rc('font', weight='bold')

  #create figure
  f = figure(figsize=(10,10))

  ax = gca()

  plot(np.arange(100), tmpData, label=r'\textbf{Line 1}', linewidth=2)

  ylabel(r'\textbf{Y-AXIS}', fontsize=20)
  xlabel(r'\textbf{X-AXIS}', fontsize=20)

  fontsize = 20
  fontweight = 'bold'
  fontproperties = {'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica'],'weight' : fontweight, 'size' : fontsize}
  ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), fontproperties)
  ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), fontproperties)

  for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
      tick.label1.set_fontsize(fontsize)

  for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
      tick.label1.set_fontsize(fontsize)



  legend()
  show()

  sys.exit()
```

And this is what I get:

[image: plot example]

Any idea what I am missing or doing wrong in order to get the axis ticks label in bold?

**EDIT**

I have updated my code using toms response. However I now have another problem, as I need to use `datetime` on the x-axis, this has not the same effect as on the normal y-axis (sorry for not putting this in in the original question, but I did not think it would change things):

```
# plotting libs
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import rc, rcParams
import matplotlib.dates as dates

# datetime
import datetime

if __name__=='__main__':

  tmpData = np.random.random( 100 )
  base = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
  arr = np.array([base + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in xrange(100)])


  # activate latex text rendering
  rc('text', usetex=True)
  rc('axes', linewidth=2)
  rc('font', weight='bold')

  rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{sfmath} \boldmath']

  #create figure
  f = figure(figsize=(10,10))

  ax = gca()

  plot(np.arange(100), tmpData, label=r'\textbf{Line 1}', linewidth=2)

  ylabel(r'\textbf{Y-AXIS}', fontsize=20)
  xlabel(r'\textbf{X-AXIS}', fontsize=20)

  ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
  ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)

  ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%Y'))
  ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator(interval=1))


  legend()
```

Now my result looks like this:

[image: updated figure]

It seems to be that the changes doe not affect the display or rather the weight of the x-axis ticks labels.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the problem is because the ticks are made in LaTeX math-mode, so the font properties don't apply.

You can get around this by adding the correct commands to the LaTeX preamble, using `rcParams`. Specifcally, you need to use `\boldmath` to get the correct weight, and `\usepackage{sfmath}` to get sans-serif font.

Also, you can use `set_tick_params` to set the font size of the tick labels.

**Tested in `python 3.12.0`, `matplotlib 3.8.0`**

### Numeric `xticklabels`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tmpData = np.random.random( 100 )

# activate latex text rendering
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('axes', linewidth=2)
plt.rc('font', weight='bold')
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{sfmath} \boldmath'

#create figure
f = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.gca()
plt.plot(np.arange(100), tmpData, label=r'\textbf{Line 1}', linewidth=2)

plt.ylabel(r'\textbf{Y-AXIS}', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel(r'\textbf{X-AXIS}', fontsize=20)

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)

plt.legend()
```

[image]

### Datetime `xticklabels`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

tmpData = np.random.random(100)
base = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
arr = np.array([base + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(100)])

# activate latex text rendering
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('axes', linewidth=2)
plt.rc('font', weight='bold')

plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{sfmath} \boldmath'

# create figure
f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

ax = plt.gca()

plt.plot(arr, tmpData, label=r'\textbf{Line 1}', linewidth=2)

plt.ylabel(r'\textbf{Y-AXIS}', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel(r'\textbf{X-AXIS}', fontsize=20)

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)

# Set x-axis major formatter and locator
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%Y'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 22):

Use

```
plt.xticks(x, weight = 'bold')
```

Comment: The question is how to make the xticklabels and yticklabels **bold** when using `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)`, and this does not do that.

Answer (score 9):

```
labels = axes.get_xticklabels() + axes.get_yticklabels()
    [label.set_fontweight('bold') for label in labels]
```

Comment: Using a list comprehension just to loop confuses the code. `for label in labels: label.set_fontweight('bold')` would make the code clearer.

Comment: The question is how to make the `xticklabels` and `yticklabels` bold when using `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)`, and this does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

- Given the original question in the OP, where the x and y axis ticks and labels are numbers.
- `[fr'\textbf{{{v}}}' for v in ax.get_xticks()]` uses 3 sets of `{}` because an f-string is also being used.

  - If only `{}` is used, `fr'\textbf{v}'`, only the first character will be bold.
- The following code uses the explicit `Axes` interface. If the implicit `pyplot` interface is used, then get the `Axes` with `ax = plt.gca()` after the plot call.
- **Tested in `python 3.12.0`,`matplotlib 3.8.0`**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random(100)

# activate latex text rendering
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('axes', linewidth=2)
plt.rc('font', weight='bold')

# create figure and Axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

ax.plot(np.arange(100), data, label=r'\textbf{Line 1}', linewidth=2)

# Set the axis labels to bold and increase the fontsize
ax.set_ylabel(r'\textbf{Y-AXIS}', fontsize=20)
ax.set_xlabel(r'\textbf{X-AXIS}', fontsize=20)

# change the tick labels to bold
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks(), [fr'\textbf{{{v}}}' for v in ax.get_xticks()], fontsize=20)
_ = ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks(), [fr'\textbf{{{round(v, 1)}}}' for v in ax.get_yticks()], fontsize=20)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make the axis labels bold automatically (i.e. without having to add \textbf every time), you could do the following

```
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

def get_new_func(axis_name):  # returns a modified version of the Axes.set_xlabel (or y) methods
    orig_func = getattr(Axes, f'set_{axis_name}label')

    def add_bold(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_args = list(args)
        new_args[0] = fr"\textbf{{{new_args[0]}}}" # modify the argument
        return orig_func(self, *new_args, **kwargs)

    return add_bold

for x in ['x', 'y']: 
    setattr(Axes, f'set_{x}label', get_new_func(x)) # modify the methods of the Axis class


x = np.linspace(0,  2 * 3.14, 20)
y = np.sin(x)
ax = plt.gca()

ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xlabel("Theta")
ax.set_ylabel("Amp")

plt.show()
```

This makes use of the fact that the `Axis.set_xlabel` and `Axis.set_ylabel` methods are attributes (in this case function objects) that can be modified by the user. The modification is done in `add_bold`, which simply calls the original function object but with a modified argument. `orig_func` and `add_bold` are defined inside of `get_new_func`  in order to correctly preserve the reference to the original method (i.e. i'm forming a closure).

Comment: The question is how to make the xticklabels and yticklabels **bold** when using `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)`, and this does not do that.

Answer (score -1):

this is another example for you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
places = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
literacy_rate = [100, 98, 90, 85, 75, 50, 30, 45, 65, 70]
female_literacy = [95, 100, 50, 60, 85, 80, 75, 99, 70, 30]
  
plt.xlabel("Places")
plt.ylabel("Percentage")
  
plt.plot(places, literacy_rate, color='blue',
         linewidth=6, label="Literacy rate")
  
plt.plot(places, female_literacy, color='fuchsia',
         linewidth=4, label="Female Literacy rate")
  
plt.legend(loc='lower left', ncol=1)
```

and the youtput will be like this:

[image: example plot]

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. The question is how to have **bold** xticklabels when using `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)`, not how to make thicker plot lines. This does not answer the question.