# Make everything bold

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

Well , I am making some plots and wants to make everything in bold font. I can can use `weight="bold"` to make bold font of label to ticks. Can also use the `prop={'weight':'bold'}` to make the legends lines bold, but I can't make the legend title bold. So, 1st question is there a way to make the legend title bold?

2nd,I tried to used matplotlib latex support to make the title bold, that did it but if I use `rc('text', usetex=True)` I cant use `weight=bold` and have to use `\textbf{}` everytime, also how do I make the ticks bold in this way.

3rd , If I use latex support then the font changes that I don't like. How do use the normal matplotlib font with using latex?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Making **everything** bold is rather easy. Just add

```
plt.rcParams["font.weight"] = "bold"
plt.rcParams["axes.labelweight"] = "bold"
```

at the top of the script.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["font.weight"] = "bold"
plt.rcParams["axes.labelweight"] = "bold"

plt.plot([2,3,1], label="foo")
plt.plot([3,1,3], label="bar")

plt.legend(title="Legend Title")
plt.xlabel("xLabel")

plt.show()
```

Comment: This does not work when using `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)` as requested in the question [resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CodKW.png). See [Make axis ticks labels bold when using usetex=True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29766827/7758804)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pass parameters into the `plt.legend` using the `prop` argument

```
legend_prop = {'weight':'bold'}
plt.plot(x, y, label='some label')
plt.legend(prop=legend_prop)
```

This would give you bold labels. Is this not what you're looking for?