# matplotlib, every text is bold after re-installing

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, seaborn

I had an error with matplotlib so I uninstalled and re-installed it using conda, but now every text is bold:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.title('Inputs characters length distribution')
sns.distplot([len(i) for i in dataset['input'].tolist()])
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]

I have:

- python 3.6.9
- conda 4.8.1
- matplotlib 3.1.1
- seaborn 0.10.0

How can I put them back to normal?

Comment: [any help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766827/matplotlib-make-axis-ticks-label-for-dates-bold)

Comment: @Ahmet nop, setting the weight using rc didn't change anything, and set_tick_params doesn't recognize either weight or fontweight.

Comment: Can you try to rebuild the font cache (e.g. via `matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()`)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It didn't solve the issue, texts are still bold.

Comment: Did you in any way manipulate the matplotlib rc file? I did face a [similar issue](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/times-new-roman-font-is-always-bold/20608), but that's when not using the default fonts.

Comment: It might get fixed by https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/16203, if you have a chance to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by setting the font manually :

```
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Verdana"
```

I still don't know what caused the issue.